# How to save scraped data into CSV file correctly with Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm looking to write some scraped data into a CSV file and open it with Excel, this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Scrapes a list of football teams and their positions in a league

url = 'https://resultados.as.com/resultados/futbol/primera/clasificacion/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tm = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'nombre-equipo')

teams = list()

count = 0

for i in tm:

    if count < 20:
        teams.append(i.text)
        count += 1
    else:
        break

pos = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'pos')

position = list()

count = 0

for i in pos:

    if count < 20:
        position.append(i.text)
        count += 1

    else:
        break

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':teams, 'Position':position})

print(df)

df.to_csv('Positions.csv', index = False)
```

It prints in console the DataFrame with the information:

```
               Name Position
0          Atlético        1
1       Real Madrid        2
2         Barcelona        3
3           Sevilla        4
4       R. Sociedad        5
5             Betis        6
6        Villarreal        7
7             Celta        8
8           Granada        9
9          Athletic       10
10          Osasuna       11
11            Cádiz       12
12         Valencia       13
13          Levante       14
14           Getafe       15
15           Alavés       16
16            Elche       17
17           Huesca       18
18  Real Valladolid       19
19            Eibar       20
```

The problem is the CSV file, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G6za.png).

I need it to look as the console printed text, in different Excel cells.

Comment: Specify `,` as a separator when you load the CSV into Excel.

Comment: As mentioned by Andrej Kesely you can set the separator in excel to be comma, but also if you want it in excel you can save it directly to excel with df.to_excel()